# When Device goes to Sleep Mode, App stops responding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

My home screen is a fragment(HomeFragment) which is having `RecyclerView`  and `Button`. Each  `RecyclerView` have some list of data(Images) and when we click on the `Button` it show all the data in another fragment [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRa11.png). My problem is that when device goes to sleep mode or timeout, And when I open my device again after 40-45 mins. And click on the `Button`, it shows **"No content Found"**. Where I am committing mistake? Can anyone suggest me how to solve this issue??

Comment: are you calling API on button click ?

Comment: @AmitVaghela Yes I am calling an API on button click

Comment: is it getting called after device wakes up ?